# Donut Pie Chart NVD3

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

below code does not display any chart my [jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/utobin/1/edit)

```
data1 = [
{
values :
[
  {"label":"One","value":29.765957771107},
  {"label":"Two","value":0},
  {"label":"Three","value":32.807804682612}
]
  }
];

nv.addGraph(function () 
            {
              var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
                .x(function (d) { return d.label; })
                .y(function (d) { return d.value; })
                .donut(true)
                .donutLabelsOutside(false)
                .showLegend(true)
              .showLabels(true);


    d3.select("#chart svg")
.datum([{"label":"One","value":29.765957771107},{"label":"Two","value":0.0},{"label":"Three","value":32.807804682612}])
        .transition().duration(100)
        .call(chart);

        return chart;
    });
```

where as if I change binding as below [Jsbin Link](http://jsbin.com/okukan/1/edit) it works.

But i want to bind my data on server side through a html helper extension. 
*what will be the correct format to pass objects to d3?* 
any Ideas?

```
      d3.select("#chart svg")
.datum(data1)
.transition().duration(2200)
.call(chart);
```

Comment: The two objects you are using have different structures.

Comment: what will be the correct format to pass objects to d3?

Comment: Well, your `data1` works, so you should format the data in that way.

Comment: sorry.. what is difference between structures.. this is my json data [{\"label\":\"One\",\"value\":29.765957771107},{\"label\":\"Two\",\"value\":0.0},{\"label\":\"Three\",\"value\":32.807804682612}]

Comment: `data1` has a single element with a list of elements under `values` whereas the object given inline has a list of elements each with `label` and `value` members (essentially what's given as `values` in `data1`).

Comment: i was expecting d3.js to go through list of objects bind them through given inline list. is that possible? I am creating this json data from MVc action

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32015/discussion-between-swapneel-and-lars-kotthoff)

Answer (score 1):

Like most of the comments to your question, I found that replacing your inline data with data1 makes it work.

```
data1 = [
{
values :
[
  {"label":"One","value":29.765957771107},
  {"label":"Two","value":0},
  {"label":"Three","value":32.807804682612}
]
  }
];

nv.addGraph(function () 
            {
              var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
                .x(function (d) { return d.label; })
                .y(function (d) { return d.value; })
                .donut(true)
                .donutLabelsOutside(false)
                .showLegend(true)
              .showLabels(true);


    d3.select("#chart svg")
.datum(data1)
        .transition().duration(100)
        .call(chart);

        return chart;
    });
```

Not sure why you have a variable to store your values and then place them inline as well but they are obviously not the same.

nvd3 expects an array of hashed configuration options and one of those is `values:`. you still have to follow the structure.

This works:

```
.datum([{values:[{"label":"One","value":29.765957771107},{"label":"Two","value":0.0},{"label":"Three","value":32.807804682612}]}])
```

All I did was take `[what you had]` and make it `[{values:[what you had]}]`

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff suggested me to prefix values:. so fix would look like this var returnvalue = "[{values:" + Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data1) + "}]";

Comment: Variable used is temporary. used just to compare with inline data